# Let Nginx or Apache Require And Accept any client certificate?

Tags: apache, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, pki

I was wondering if it was possible to configure either of these servers to both require a client certificate while at the same time not completely verifying it?

So far, I tried looking at the SSLVerifyClient configuration fields but the options seem to either make it optional or required and actually verified.

Comment: What good is "you'll need a passport to enter, but you could also create one yourself"? _requiring_ a certificate, and at the same time stating that you'd also accept an invalid one, is just that

Comment: My goal is not to do any authentication but to see if the client supported client authentication in the first place.

Comment: In that case, please read [help/on-topic] and [ask]: Your question hits multiple reasons to be closed/off-topic here: It's really broad (e.g. nginx or apache), is rather about configuration than programming, doesn't contain code or what you did already (a [mcve]), asks for documentation on this and doesn't state clearly what you observe and intend. You might want to rephrase it (start with the use of "require", and make it about programming: let us know what you already have) to be on-topic here, or find another site in the stackexchange network where it would be on-topic.